# How can I transfer my all contacts from old HTC Wildfifre android 2.1 to LG Optimus Vu

Tags: contacts, backup, htc-wildfire

I just want to transfer all contacts from old HTC Wildfire with android version 2.1 to new LG Optimus Vu with android version 4.0. I have used different apps but still I am unable to transfer contacts and an unexpected error occures. Another issue is that I can't move contacts to SD card because LG Optimus Vu does not supports SD card. Please recommend a simple and easy way or an app which is helpful to transfer contacts to the new LG optimus Vu from HTC Wildfire.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few steps:

1. Open the contacts app on the Wildfire
2. Tap the menu button, select to "Export" your contacts to SDCard. This will result in a `00001.vcf` file on your SDCard.
3. Now use any way you like to get the exported file to the Optimus:

   - Mail/GMail it to your account
   - Send it via Bluetooth
   - Copy to your computer, and then to the new device's internal SDCard
   - ...
4. On the Optimus, open the contacts app
5. As above, use the Export/Import feature to import the `.vcf` file

If in step 3 you chose to Mail/GMail the `.vcf` file, you most likely will be able to open it directly from the attachment, which should cause it to be offered for import into your contacts app (I never tried that variant, so I'm not sure about it).

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Contact Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vcard.android) and exported all my contact data and groups to a single .vcf file, afterwards I mailed it to my mail account and then downloaded it on my new phone and there imported it with the same app which I used for the export. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be exporting all contacts to Google account and then Sync it in a new device.